# Could not load definitions from resources

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, rapidminer

I have a (hopefully) very basic question.  I'm very unfamiliar with Ant, I'm just trying to use a build file so I can write some plugins for an open source application I found recently, Rapid Miner.  I've been trying to compile it with Eclipse (following Eclipses.org's own instructions on how to do so.)  Every time I click Run though I get an error that looks like this:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\jcarr14\Eclipse\Workspace\RapidMiner_Unuk\build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\jcarr14\Eclipse\Workspace\RapidMiner_Unuk\build.xml:329: taskdef class   com.oracle.appbundler.AppBundlerTask cannot be found
using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Total time: 306 milliseconds
```

It seems to me that there must be a file missing, but I can't figure out where it is supposed to be and as a result, I can't figure out if it is actually there or not, or even if Eclipse is the culprit.  I did go into the Eclipse folder and look for a net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml, but was unable to locate anything.

I'm assuming that it's possible the problem is not with Eclipse at all, but with Rapid Miner.  So I looked for that same location inside of the RapidMiner project structure and was unable to find it.  I have also posted a similar question to this one on RapidMiner's forums, just in case this is RapidMiner specific.

I suppose the basic question I need answered is how to check if Ant is installed properly in Eclipse.  Once I know that Eclipse is working fine I can then throw all my focus on figuring out what is wrong with RapidMiner...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you need to install [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I'm looking into this.  It should have occurred to me I might just be missing a library.  Now I just need to figure out where to put this thing...

Comment: Look where is your ant install (find out where is the executable). put the jar in `{ant_install}/lib` folder.

Comment: THis seems to have worked.  I just added an external jar for antcontrib to my Ant settings in Eclipse and I was able to pass that part of the build process.  Sadly, I'm not hung up somewhere else, but I'll try and work on that on my own for a little while before complaining on SO...