# Compile Error java project with netbeans8.2

Tags: java, netbeans, ant, kotlin

I try to write a project with netbeans 8.2 on my computer. 
when I copy it and import this project in another computer and try to compile it with netbeans 8.2 I see this error.please help me if possible: 
this is an error:

```
"Could not load definitions from resource org/jetbrains/kotlin/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found. 
ant -f C:\\Users\\QUQNTOM\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\C hangefile -Dnb.internal.action.name=run run 
init: 
Deleting: C:\Users\QUQNTOM\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Change file\build\built-jar.properties 
deps-jar: 
Could not load definitions from resource org/jetbrains/kotlin/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found. 
Updating property file: C:\Users\QUQNTOM\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Change file\build\built-jar.properties"
```

[image]

Comment: probably this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15621557/784540

Comment: Tnx. I solve this problem. the Error was to build-impl. xml I create a new project and replace it with built-impl. xml in my project and set its path to my coastline lib.

Answer (score 0):

This problem will be created when you install the IntelliJ from JetBrains and NetBeans at the same time. The .conf files are mixed, or whatever, I don't know what's happening behind the scenes. The only solution I figured out that, I removed both of the IDEs, and reinstalled the JDK and the JRE also. That will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone, having two versions of Netbeans, 8 and 12. In version 8, activate the Kotlin plug-in and create the file.reference.kotlin-runtime.jar = .. / .. / .. folder again. /AppData/Roaming/NetBeans/8.1/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-runtime.jar and then work again